# Cannot map domain to cluster in GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, dns, google-cloud-dns

I am just starting out with `kubernetes`. I have created a simple app which is working fine with the external IP address. It's a `mongodb-express` with `mongo-db` backend. I am trying to get a domain name mapped to it, instead of the IP address.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-express
  labels:
    app: mongo-express
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo-express
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo-express
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongo-express
        image: mongo-express
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
        env:
        - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME
          etc
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-express-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo-express
  type: LoadBalancer  
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8081
```

This was a walk in the park with AWS. Simply created a zone and added the name servers to the domain name provider, however in GCP this does not work. I have created a zone in cloudDNS but cannot seem to map it to the cluster. The documentation is a bit complex for me to understand. Can someone help?

```
kubernetes              ClusterIP      10.28.0.1     <none>         443/TCP        51m
mongo-express-service   LoadBalancer   10.28.7.249   34.69.73.210   80:30055/TCP   42m
mongodb-service         ClusterIP      10.28.1.163   <none>         27017/TCP      45m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cloud DNS** config is the same as the **route53** configuration. You can add the **CName** record or **A** record as per requirement.

For a simple use case, you can follow this document which is regarding adding static IP to DNS and mapping the domain.

As you have already exposed the service with type **LoadBalancer** you can follow from here

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip#configuring_your_domain_name_records

Make sure your Nameserver are set correctly

> If your nameserver is Cloud DNS: Follow Cloud DNS Quickstart guide to
> configure DNS A record for your domain name with the reserved IP
> address of your application.
>
> If your nameserver is another provider: Refer to your DNS service's
> documentation on setting DNS A records to configure your domain name.
> If you choose to use Cloud DNS instead, refer to Migrating to Cloud
> DNS.

**Extra** :

You can also use the external DNS to auto add the **ingress** records to Cloud DNS.

Example : https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/gke.md

Comment: Apparently, all I needed to do was to add a record in the Cloud DNS. Couldn't have got that without your answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: glad to hear that, feel free to add comment on issue still if you face any.